# Regex mountPage with Wicket

Tags: java, wicket

I need to be able to mount a page with Wicket using a regex:

```
mountPage("/app/create", CreatePage.class);
mountPage("/^[0-9a-zA-Z-]+$", ViewPage.class); // Like this
```

I have tried [PatternMountedMapper](https://github.com/55minutes/fiftyfive-wicket/blob/master/fiftyfive-wicket-core/src/main/java/fiftyfive/wicket/mapper/PatternMountedMapper.java) from 55minutes.

```
mount(new PatternMountedMapper("/#{hash:^[0-9a-zA-Z-]+$}", ViewPage.class));
```

However this one catches even not a-z, A-Z, 0-9 pattern, even paths `/_ah/admin/` so it does not work. What solution is best fit for this requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use '$' instead if '#' and set Exact to true:

```
        mount(new PatternMountedMapper("/${hash:^[0-9a-zA-Z-]+$}", TargetPage.class).setExact(true));
```